# Titanium android keyboard hide, when soft keyboard visible

Tags: android, titanium-mobile

There i have created a chat app, all is working fine. but there is 2 problem.
first: my chat window contains, one header view one table view, which contains the rows with chat labels(text) one text field and button to type words.

now suppose when there is nothing in the chat table only one row with chat label., when i try to type any thing in the keyboard the chat labels get out of the view i mean as the window is opened the table view pushes it self up.. any how can i resize the table view when the keyboard gets opened.

second : weird problem. when i load old chats and loop through them and append to table view. it dosent index it self as per the loop some times.. some table rows get above the previous row

Example . one tableview row have chat time of 11:52 am and other 12:00
some times the 12:00 gets above the 11:52 row. though i am appending the rowin the loop..
please any suggestion will be helpful.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextField.blur();
```

will hide the keyboard.

Example below is an event listener for the DONE button. When the button is clicked, the keyboard disappears.

```
done.addEventListener('click',function(){ nameTxt.blur(); });
```

Comment: ok that does hides the keyboard and shows the chat.. but if you look in skype or google chat app, you will see that the view resizes when the keyboard is shown and shows what ever is written in the first level.. can that be done with titanium.

Comment: sorry i am not too familiar with it